# Left Join not working as intended yet SQL accepts it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

**HomeController.php**

```
public function index()
{      
    $employees = DB::table('timings')
                ->distinct()
                ->selectRaw("timings.employee_id, min(time_logged) AS minTime, max(time_logged) AS maxTime")
                ->leftJoin('employees','timings.employee_id','=','employees.employee_id')
                ->where( DB::raw('cast(time_logged AS date)') , DB::raw('CURDATE()'))
                ->groupBy('timings.employee_id', DB::raw('cast(time_logged AS date)') )
                ->get();

    return view('home',compact('employees'));
}
```

**Actual SQL**

```
employee_id  |   minTime     |    maxTime     
1                2019-03-25       09:00:00 2019-03-25 14:00:00
...
```

**Result**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [employee_id] => 1 
    [minTime] => 2019-03-25 09:00:00 
    [maxTime] => 2019-03-25 14:00:00 
)
...
```

For some reason, MYSQL accepts Left Join but nothing happens! I have 2 tables, Employees & timings. Whether I include leftJoin or comment it out the code works yet the EMPLOYEE table wont show. I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: What is the **actual SQL** generated? Please post it.

Comment: @Dai Added in Edit

Comment: @NazarAbubaker you still haven't included the generated SQL.

Comment: This is the SQL he is generating: 
```select distinct timings.employee_id,min(time_logged) AS minTime,max(time_logged) AS maxTime from `timings` left join `employees` on `timings`.`employee_id` = `employees`.`employee_id` where cast(time_loggedASdate) = CURDATE() group by `timings`.`employee_id`, cast(time_loggedASdate)```

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? To me, both outputs show the same data

Comment: Output should include Employee First / Last name & Avatar

Comment: Are you forgetting to add the first name , lastname and avatar column selectors in the query? in selectRaw().

Comment: @NareshKumar That was it!

Comment: Are you sure `leftJoin` is appropriate here? `timings` (which is the left table) seems to be dependant on `employees` so there's no way you'd have a timing without a corresponding employee. Maybe you need a `rightJoin` to get all employees even if they have no timings associated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not selected details from `employee` table

```
->selectRaw("timings.employee_id, min(time_logged) AS minTime, max(time_logged) AS maxTime,employees.first_name, employees.last_name")
```